# Awk how to print the next line of a specific expression but only of it contains a number

Tags: awk

Here is a *test.txt* file

```
sometext
someothertext
...
lol
74
hhhhh
lol
789AA
```

I want a bash command that only displays:

```
74
```

For this I have tried:

```
awk '$0 == "lol" {i=1;next};i && i++ <= 1' test.txt
```

which for now displays

```
74
789AA
```

So, how can I augment this command so that it only displays a line that **only** contains a number (74) ?

Thanks

Comment: What you have is pure `awk` there is no shell code involve

Comment: @Paolo no , it does not

Comment: So you don't mean _if it contains a number_, but you mean _if it consists only of a number_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` should work for you:

```bash
awk 'p == "lol" && $0+0 == $0; {p = $0}' file

74
```

`$0+0 == $0` will return `true` only when `$0` contains a number only.

Comment: what if I have lol\n74 but then also lol\n75 , I want the command to display 74 and 75

Comment: This would work only if OP have exactly one line containing only number. You should get rid of `; exit` and add a condition `p=="lol" && /^[0-9]+$/`.

Comment: @ailauli69: Try my updated answer now, may be this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` code.

```
awk -v RS='\nlol\n[0-9]+\n' 'RT{gsub(/^\n+|\n+$/,"",RT);split(RT,arr,ORS);print arr[2]}' Input_file
```

Comment: It will print `lol\n74`, not just `74`